# HTML5/Javascript timeout doesn't finish function

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, timeout

I made a loop function to slowly fade an image.

```
var ctx; // this is the canvas already defined
function nextPic(i)
    {
        trans = 1; //resets transparent var to 1
        fadeloop('out'); //starts loop
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clears canvas, this doesn't work
        alert("done"); //this doesn't work either

    }
    function fadeloop(f){ //loop that fades
        if(f == 'out'){ //make sure it wants to shade out
            setTimeout(function () { //timed delay for fading out
                fadeImgOut(); //calls function to fade out by .01
                if(trans>0.0){ //if faded out break out of loop
                    fadeloop('out'); //if not restart function
                }
            },10);
        }
    }
    function fadeImgOut(){ //function that fades out
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        ctx.globalAlpha = trans;
        trans = trans - .01;
    }
```

A button calls nextpic. It will slowly transparent the image then fade in another one. Right now it fades the image out till trans = .01. Doesn't continue on to the alert("done") or the canvas reset. Any ideas I've looked it over and over and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the web inspector? I'm guessing the script is crashing for whatever reason if the alert("done") is not firing.

Comment: Where do you define canvas.width & canvas.height?

Comment: Also, where are you declaring 'trans' right now it looks like each function has a local declaration of 'trans' but I don't see any declaration of trans outside of the functions as you have done for ctx.

Comment: No `var` keyword. So if he didn't explicitly declare it someplace, it's a global - and shouldn't be a problem here. What I'm wondering is if the OP doesn't realize that his initial call to `fadeloop` returns immediately rather than at the end of all that recursion due to the `setTimeout`.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors and nothing is crashing. It just completely ignores it. canvas is defined near the top. Forgot to include that var but it works. Some variable are declared but not on here cause I don't know where to stick it in the sample code. Canvas, ctx, trans are all declared.

Comment: kennis shouldn't it still alert?

Answer (score 1):

I tested with similar functions. The code is:

```
    var j = 100;
    (function(){
        a();  // step 1;
        alert("hello world!"); // step 3; Fired without almost no time delay.
    })()

    function a(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           b();
           if(j>1){
              a();
           }
        }, 10);　// step 2;  push the callback into a queue, and a() ends. 
    }

    function b(){
        if(j > 1){
            j--;
        }
    }
```

The result is: alert is fired immediately without any delay. And the result is right.

**Because** setTimeout is asynchronous function. That means when a() gets executed at first time, the callback function in setTimeout will be pushed to a queue waiting for firing. Then the alert() in `expression function` is fired.

I don't know why your alert isn't fired. Maybe some errors occured.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve you problem, but might simplify it a bit.

You are using fadeloop recursively, but you can simply accomplish this by a while loop, which make it easier to trace/debug. And not have to figure out how deep inside the recursion you are.

The only problem i can come up with is does setTimeout have a method signature of setTimeout(function, time)? everything else look correct.

Comment: the while loop doesn't work. It glitches and the guides told me to write it like this. Yeah the setTimeout does.

Answer (score 0):

trinity's answer is correct, though the alert not firing does make it sound like you have some other error interfering with the posted code. FWIW, here's a minimal page with your code that demonstrates that it is working as described:

```html
<!doctype html>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = nextPic;
img.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/ads/img/careers2-ad-header-so-crop.png';

function nextPic(i) {
  trans = 1; //resets transparent var to 1
  fadeloop('out'); //starts loop
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  alert("done");
}
function fadeloop(f){ //loop that fades
  if(f == 'out'){ //make sure it wants to shade out
    setTimeout(function () { //timed delay for fading out
      fadeImgOut(); //calls function to fade out by .01
      if(trans>0.0){ //if faded out break out of loop
        fadeloop('out'); //if not restart function
      }
    },10);
  }
}
function fadeImgOut(){ //function that fades out
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.globalAlpha = trans;
  trans = trans - .01;
}
</script>
```

Note that the way you have things ordered (you subtract from trans after drawing and *then* check to see if you should repeat the loop), it's correct that you'll end near .01. You'll need to reorder things to make sure you hit 0.

Also be careful with repeated floating point subtraction: you aren't hitting the values that you think you are (and you'll never reach exactly 0 with this loop). A very minimal change would give you a start on getting it correct (this assumes your image has already been drawn once and so it's ok to subtract from trans before calling fadeImgOut):

```js
function fadeloop(f){ //loop that fades
  if(f == 'out'){ //make sure it wants to shade out
    setTimeout(function () { //timed delay for fading out
      trans = Math.max(0, trans - .01);
      fadeImgOut(); //calls function to fade out by .01
      if(trans>0.0){ //if faded out break out of loop
        fadeloop('out'); //if not restart function
      }
    },10);
  }
}
function fadeImgOut(){ //function that fades out
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.globalAlpha = trans;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```